# Is there a way to typecast a variable on the fly while using the ** operator?

Tags: python, json

I am parsing a json file which contains keyword arguments for a function `some_function` which is called in succession. 
**JSON FILE**

```
{
    "keyword_arg1": 123,
    "keyword_arg2": [2, 3],
    ...
}
```

**PSEUDO-CODE**

```
args = parse_json(JSON_FILE)
some_function(some_argument='some arguments will also be passed manually', **args)
```

Now, unfortunately, `some_function` requires actually a tuple as `keyword_arg2` argument and not a `list`. Is there a way to keep my code simple and typecast the json-parsed `keyword_arg2` from a `list` to a `tuple` on the fly?

Comment: Python doesn't have type casting (at least, not in any sense that I feel the term has any useful meaning). Every value has an unchanging type; a "cast" simply produces a *new* value constructed from the old value.

Comment: Additionally to what @chepner said: In python, we usually use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). This means that your method would only enforce that you pass a `tuple` if there is any reason that it actually needs a tuple while other iterables can not be used. In this specific case, I can not imagine a case where a tuple could be used but a list could not. What is the error you get if you just pass the list? Where does `some_function` come from?

Comment: @chepner okay... but how would you name it then? :D

Comment: @He3lixxx While it would be nice if `some_function` accepted general iterables, I find it all too easy to believe that it could do something like `x = (1,2) + keyword_arg2` internally, which would necessitate an actual tuple.

Comment: @He3lixxx `torch.nn.Conv1d` expects tuples for `stride` and `kernel_size`

Comment: @c0mr4t There's nothing here to name: you have a value of one type, you need a value of another. You need to create that value.

Comment: @c0mr4t If you have a particular function in mind, please use that, rather than generalizing the question more than necessary.

Comment: @chepner I just realized that `torch.nn.Conv1d` accepts lists as well eventhough it is not mentioned in the docs. Got a cuda runtime error but it was related to another issue. So, I think I leave the question as it is?

Comment: @c0mr4t Fair enough, and good to hear that it's not specifically requiring a tuple  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the existing dict first.

```
args['keyword_arg2'] = tuple(args['keyword_arg2'])
some_function(..., **args)
```